# Bundle.main.resourcePath returning nil in my flutter plugin, after working fine previously

Tags: swift, flutter, flutter-plugin, .app

I've made a test flutter app that uses a plugin I made that simply retrieves the path of the resources folder in my .app and returns it to my dart code.

This works completely fine in the example project generated with the plugin, and has previously worked with my app. I didn't use the plugin for a while after this and it went unused, up until recently as I now had an actual use for it so included it in my code once again. Now the plugin doesn't seem to work with any project I add it to, even freshly made ones.

My plugin consists of this dart code:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class MacBundleUtils {
  static const MethodChannel _channel =
      const MethodChannel('mac_bundle_utils');

  static Future<String?> get getResourcesDir async {
    final String? resDir = await _channel.invokeMethod('getResourcesDir');
    return resDir;
  }
}
```

and this swift code:

```
import Cocoa
import FlutterMacOS

public class MacBundleUtilsPlugin: NSObject, FlutterPlugin {
  public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
    let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "mac_bundle_utils", binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger)
    let instance = MacBundleUtilsPlugin()
    registrar.addMethodCallDelegate(instance, channel: channel)
  }

  public func handle(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
    switch call.method {
    case "getResourcesDir":
        result(Bundle.main.resourcePath)
    default:
      result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
    }
  }
}
```

I then try to retrieve this path and print it to the console with this one simple line:

```
print(await MacBundleUtils.getResourcesDir);
```

This however returns the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
```

What could I be doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually came across the solution shortly after posting this question.
I was trying to access Bundle.main too early as my code was in void main().
After moving my code to execute after loading with initState() like so:

```
@override
void initState() { //for linux app, tells user if permissions aren't correct
  super.initState();

  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
    print(await MacBundleUtils.getResourcesDir);
  });
}
```

it works with no issues.